# what's the use of setAction() function with intent

Tags: android

What does setAction() actually do?

```
    public void call(View view) {
        Intent call_view= new Intent(this, call.class);
        call_view.setAction(Task.ACTION_INCREMENT);
        startService(call_view);
    }
```

Comment: Read [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) for better understanding. It's rather wide topic for short description.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to set actions to be done by the intent such as answering/dialing phone calls. Check the constant values for [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)